# NodeJS - mysql stored procedure giving null row if no record found from Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am calling a MySQL stored procedure using [MySQL](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) for NodeJS. However, when there is no matching record from the stored procedure the lib returns the object with `null` key values.

Below is the Stored Procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `ABC_AP_GET_LOGIN_DETAILS`(v_eml varchar(50))
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        U.ABC_AP_USERS_ID uid
        ,U.FIRST_NAME fn
        ,U.LAST_NAME ln
        ,U.MOB_NUM mob
        ,U.PWD_HASH pwdhs
        ,D.ABC_AP_DEPARTMENTS_MASTER_ID did
        ,D.`NAME` dn
        ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT UR.ROLE_MASTER_ID ORDER BY UR.ABC_AP_USER_ROLES_ID ASC SEPARATOR ',') rids
    FROM ABC_AP_USERS U
    INNER JOIN ABC_AP_USER_ROLES UR ON UR.USER_ID = U.ABC_AP_USERS_ID
    INNER JOIN ABC_AP_DEPARTMENTS_MASTER D ON D.ABC_AP_DEPARTMENTS_MASTER_ID = U.DEPARTMENT_ID
    WHERE U.EMAIL_ID = v_eml
    AND U.IS_ACTIVE = TRUE;
END
```

When there is no USERS for specified `v_eml`. It returns the following:

```
[ [ { uid: null,
      fn: null,
      ln: null,
      mn: null,
      pwdhs: null,
      did: null,
      dn: null,
      rids: null } ],
  { fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 0,
    insertId: 0,
    serverStatus: 34,
    warningCount: 0,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0 } ]
```

How can I make the change to return empty array instead of `Object` with null values if no record matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens to be a default behavior of `GROUP_CONCAT` and to avoid this(null row) we have to add `GROUP BY` at the end of the query or Stored Procedure.

So, the updated Stored Procedure is as

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `ABC_AP_GET_LOGIN_DETAILS`(v_eml varchar(50))
BEGIN
  SELECT 
    U.ABC_AP_USERS_ID uid
        ,U.FIRST_NAME fn
        ,U.LAST_NAME ln
        ,U.MOB_NUM mob
        ,U.PWD_HASH pwdhs
        ,D.ABC_AP_DEPARTMENTS_MASTER_ID did
        ,D.`NAME` dn
        ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT UR.ROLE_MASTER_ID ORDER BY UR.ABC_AP_USER_ROLES_ID ASC SEPARATOR ',') rids
  FROM ABC_AP_USERS U
  INNER JOIN ABC_AP_USER_ROLES UR ON UR.USER_ID = U.ABC_AP_USERS_ID
    INNER JOIN ABC_AP_DEPARTMENTS_MASTER D ON D.ABC_AP_DEPARTMENTS_MASTER_ID = U.DEPARTMENT_ID
  WHERE U.EMAIL_ID = v_eml
    AND U.IS_ACTIVE = TRUE
    GROUP BY UR.USER_ID;
END
```